# Notepad++ comment all lines containing string or all bookmarked lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I wanted to comment out some java code using Notepad++
e.g.

```
StringBuffer sbTest = new StringBuffer();
sbTest.append("aaa");
sbTest.append("bbb");
sbTest.append("ccc");
sbTest.append("aaa");
sbTest.append("ddd");
```

Lets say I want to comment out all lines containing "aaa" How to do that in Notepad++
I know a procedure to bookmark the lines containing this text but how to comment out these bookmarked lines I am not sure.
Can you please suggest some way I can do this using Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regular Expression find and replace search for `(.*"aaa")` and replace that with `//\1`.

- `"aaa"` is what you are searching for and `.*` means you pickup characters before that on the line and the brackets create a group of all the characters searched for.
- `\1` then inserts the group into the replacement.

Comment: Hi, it replaces the line by comment. I need to add // in front of every line which contains "aaa" but if I try your solution I can find the line but when I add "\1//" in to replace it replaces the line by //);

Comment: I think the problem is that you are missing out the `\1` from the replacement string. That is important as it selects the first group. That or you didn't include the brackets around the find term.

Comment: @AmolRamkrishnaPatil have I answered your question or haven't you had time to look yet?

Answer (score 3):

Using 'find and replace' in regular expression mode:

- Find what: `(.*aaa)`
- Replace with: `//\1`
- Click on 'Replace All'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution. meh-uk has provided correct answer first hence I have selected it as accepted answer but you definitely make it more clear.. hence +1